# What is the path to the folder my Python script lies in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, operating-system, sys

I want my Python scripts to be able to be run by people with other folder set ups too, so using a reference to a folder the Python script is saved to makes a lot of sense.

Example: If my script, "script_1.py" is run from "C:\My Scripts\script_1.py" I want to save "C:\My Scripts" to a variable I can use.

However, I can't get it too work.

I've import os and sys, but using `os.path.dirname(__file__)` or `os.path.abspath(__file__)` gives the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-24-1830932ce69b>", line 1, in <module>
os.path.dirname(__file__)

NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

Using `sys.executable` gives me the address to where my Python is installed (I think?? It doesn't give me what I'm looking for anyhow).

I was also given the advice to try `os.environ['_']` but that gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-26-6c75f8b10c6d>", line 1, in <module>
os.environ['_']

File "D:\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
   raise KeyError(key) from None

KeyError: '_'
```

I'm running my code from Windows 10 by the way. It's Python 3.

Comment: `__file__` is giving you an error because you're using it in an interactive session, there's no file, trying to get the file dosen't make sense

Comment: @jonatan i didn't know that but it makes a lot of sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the location of your script.

```
import os
import sys
script_location = os.path.split(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))[0]
```

Comment: When would this be better than `script_location = __file__`? If imported, `__file__` will still work, but this won't

Comment: Good question...  Never really thought about it.  I guess the only real difference is that `__file__` is going to give you the location of the current file you are executing from, not necessarily your main program... so it depends on what you are trying to figure out?